# skip subdirectory when replacing underscore to hyphen from urls using .htaccess code

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, directory

I have to replace _ (underscore) with -(hyphen) from urls for the SEO purpose.I have hundreds of files so I can't change filenames one by one.So I wrote some **.htaccess** code to do that.

This is the code I am using.

```
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

It successfully changing my urls from underscore to hyphen.

Now I have one subdirectory named "**administrator**" and I dont want this directory urls to replace from underscore to hyphen.

So I want to skip urls of this directory to skip from .htaccess code.

Please help me how to skip this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Negative lookahead**:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!administrator/)([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L,NC]
```

This will skip `/administrator/` sub-directory from this rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can also exclude separately:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator/
RewriteRule ^([^_]*)_(.*)$ /$1-$2 [R=301,L]
```

It's easier if you then need to exclude more than one directory, as it is just necessary to add the same line again.